# PHP: I want to have an Admin Area in my Webpage so how can I make my Admin area in PHP

Tags: php

PHP make an Admin Area ,to check the User name and Password and then load to another Page

Comment: @ibrahom: and what is your question ?

Comment: do you want someone to code this for you? have a look around google and find some examples

Comment: I think you need to read a book. The question is very vague. You need to learn the basics like Sessions, POST, GET, etc.

These sort of questions cannot be answered by the Stackoverflow users.

Comment: do you mean, validating the username and password inputted by a certain user?

Comment: Sometimes the best way to start learning something is to dive in and actually try to use it to solve a problem .. cut the OP a little slack. Re-tagging as beginner.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest learning a CMS like Joomla or Drupal. It takes the headache out of creating admin areas. And, if your asking this question, I think it might be easier than learning to write it in PHP.

Comment: We've all gotta start somewhere. The OP might not be interested in abandoning what he's done thus far.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a *really* big hurry, you can try something like [PHPMaker](http://www.hkvstore.com/phpmaker/). It can examine your database tables and generate the typical create / update / modify / delete forms that you would need to manage users.

Note: I am ***not*** endorsing PHPMaker, in fact I really don't care for the code that it actually generates. Its no better and possibly worse than `scaffolding` provided by MVC frameworks. I posted it as an alternative to telling you '*just use a MVC framework with scaffolding and re-write everything you have done so far*'.

However, when lazy, it can be handy.

The real solution is write your own intuitive admin interface.

Answer (score 1):

there's no point in writing this whole code for you. You should try to read some books / articles and then try to code something simple by yourself to see how PHP actually works.

You should check first some simple tutorials first. Like:

- http://www.swish-db.com/tutorials/view.php/tid/601
- http://www.webdesign.org/web-programming/php/register-login-script.8721.html

Also, consider reading the PHP documentation. There are some nice tips there (also discussions for each topic are usually interesting).

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways you could achieve this. I recommend using [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) to check if the user logged in with a valid username and password. You can store the usernames and passwords in a database or code it directly in your php-code. Storing your passwords in a database might be a security issue as long as you store them in plain-text. You should use a password hash (created with md5($string)) instead and compare the hashed user input with your database.
Just use an HTML-Form where the user enters his name and password, pass the two entered values as session-variables and check whether they match the username and password you stored. If so the desired page can load.

Comment: You should add that passwords shouldn't be stored in plain text in the database.  The proper way to do it is to create a hash string of the user's password and store that in the database, then every time the user logs in create a hash from the supplied string and compare it with the one in the database.

Comment: I first thought about mentioning it but was not sure if it would be too much for the OP. Edited it now.

Answer (score 0):

You could try that:

http://www.tutorialized.com/view/tutorial/Simple-PHP-Login-Script/52350